# Python logging while crontab in docker container

Tags: python, linux, docker, cron

I'm running a python job which logs into a file:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', filename='/app/logs/ups_tracking.log')
self.logger = logging.getLogger('TRACK-UPS')
```

When running the job manually, the log files are well created / incremented with new entries.

When running through crontab (syntax below), the logs are not written as expected.

```
### TRACKING UPS ###
* * * * * python /app/UPS/parcels.py

root@91067d2217e7:/app/logs# service cron status
[ ok ] cron is running.
```

I'm running the whole thing in a docker container, with the dockerfile below:

```
#Create the flask custom image
FROM python:latest
    
# Place your flask application on the server
COPY ./back /app/

WORKDIR /app

# Install requirements.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip 
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat cron

COPY ./config/init.sh /tmp/init.sh

RUN chmod +x /tmp/init.sh

# Copy crontab_file file to the cron.d directory
COPY ./config/crontab_file /etc/cron.d/crontab_file
 
# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab_file

# Apply cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab_file

# Start CRON service
RUN service cron start

EXPOSE 8889
ENTRYPOINT ["/tmp/init.sh"]
```

Am I missing something here ?

Thanks !

Comment: `service` doesn't really work in Docker.  A container only runs one process, so you might need to run the cron daemon in a separate container.

Comment: Weird because if I create a basic cron entry (* * * * * echo « toto » > myfile) the log file is created

Answer (score 1):

```
# Start CRON service
RUN service cron start
```

means crond is running only during that `RUN` stage.

seeing that I wonder if you are starting cron in `/tmp/init.sh` too ?